# I am trying to run a maven compile on my project, I am getting this error message

Tags: java, spring, maven

---

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project codec-energy-phase3: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\ArEgOn\.m2\repository\com\hpe\iot\codec\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\codec-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar; invalid distance too far back
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\ArEgOn\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] /E:/work/iot-codec/codec-energy-phase3/src/main/java/com/tcl/iot/codec/energy/phase3/encoder/base/BaseEncoder.java:[12,25] cannot access com.hpe.iot.codec.CodecException
[ERROR] bad class file: C:\Users\ArEgOn\.m2\repository\com\hpe\iot\codec\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\codec-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar(com/hpe/iot/codec/CodecException.class)
[ERROR] unable to access file: corrupted zip file
[ERROR] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[ERROR] /E:/work/iot-codec/codec-energy-phase3/src/main/java/com/tcl/iot/codec/energy/phase3/encoder/base/BaseEncoder.java:[25,56] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class CodecException
[ERROR] location: class com.tcl.iot.codec.energy.phase3.encoder.base.BaseEncoder<T>
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project codec-energy-phase3: Compilation failure
```

I am getting the above error log when I am trying to compile my project using maven.
Can anyone please help me to figure out possible causes and solutions.

Comment: can you post your pom file?

Comment: acctually i have solved the problem...jar file was corrupted...anywy ty

Comment: so post a response for the others please